# Отличие организации многопоточности на Java и C++ (boost)

Tags: boost, многопоточность, java, c++

Сейчас разбираюсь с многопоточностью в Java: блокирование объектов, объекты условий, synchronized и т.д. Вопрос в следующем: если например потом разбираться с многопоточностью в том же boost для C++. Сильное будет отличие?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вообще-то, суть многопоточного программирования одинакова практически во всех языках. Так что если разберётесь с Java, то различие с C++ будет небольшое.

Comment: Не знаю как там в boost, но вообще-то в Java и в C++ совсем по-разному многопоточность организуется. 
В Java надо наследовать Runnable и использовать synchronized, тогда как в С++ - передавать callback и использовать мутексы/семафоры.

Comment: Согласен на счёт "мутексы/семафоры". Но в Java такие вещи также есть. Но треды в "boost" похожи на джавовские. Те же sleep, notify и т.д. А вообще, я говорил не про синтаксис, а про саму концепцию многопоточного программирования. Если поймёшь в Java, то не составит труда разобраться и в плюсах.

Comment: Я бы всё-таки рекомендовал начать с плюсов, там сложнее.

Comment: Зачем начинать со сложного? Лучше начать на Java - там прозрачнее и яснее. Зачем голову забивать туманом?

Comment: А posix-threads без ООП еще проще. Только для достаточно общих случаев много мелочевки надо самому ручками писать. Тривиальное же распараллеливание пишется элементарно.

Comment: А еще есть OpenMP. Хотя он больше расчитан на параллельные вычисления, обычную многопоточность на нем тоже можно довольно легко реализовывать.